# Django localize built-in widgets

Tags: javascript, django, localization, django-admin, widget

I use Django built-in widgets like AdminSplitDateTime. However, strings used in this widget aren't localized as they're in JavaScript. How to correct that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you taked a look the Django documentation about [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#specifying-translation-strings-in-javascript-code) subject? Or maybe it's something else that you want?

The main idea is that JS does not have a native implementation of gettext, so you need to use an special catalog.

Comment: Ok, it seems this is it. I had to change url pattern to:
`js_info_dict = {
    'packages': ('django.conf','django.contrib.admin',),
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
)`
and now it works. Thx to @pyriku and Ruslan Popov with his case: http://dpaste.com/626332/

Comment: @alekwisnia: been looking for this for a few weeks now, thank you for the snippet